# react API calls(leaflet, ip Geolocation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

working on a challenge from frontend mentor.an ip address tracker with Api calls feom react leaflet map and IP geolocation API and i'm having issues using the value of the props for the lattitude and longtittude.this my code

```
function App() {
  const [address,setAddress] = useState({})

  useEffect(()=>{
    try{
        axios.get('https://geo.ipify.org/api/v2/country,city?apiKey=at_FmUFGKJxGxjnnNkYNr9W2TAv3XShk&ipAddress=8.8.8.8')
      .then((res) => setAddress(res.data))
    }catch(err){
      console.log('error')
    }},[])
 
  

  return (
    <div className="App font-Rubik">
      <Map position={{...address}} />
    </div>
  );
}


`map component`


  const Map = (props) => {
  const lat = props.position?.location?.lat;
  const lng = props.position?.location?.lng;
  const location = [37.40599,-122.078514];

  console.log([lat,lng])
`when logged on the console it shows the vaue of lat and lng  but when I assign the values to the const location(location=[lat,lng]) it throws an error and refuses to render.`

  return (
    <MapContainer
      className="h-screen z-10 pt-16"
      center={location}
      zoom={13}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={location}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: LatLng.js:32 Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined)
    at new LatLng

Comment: The error is not from the components shared above, can you share the content of the LatLng.js file and how it is used in the application as well?

Comment: im not sure what you mean,those are the components.except you mean the content of the geolation API.and i forgot to add..it works when i change and save but when I reload the page it displays the error and refuses to render.

Comment: Can you enclose the creation of the location object in an if-else case when both `lat` and `lng` are true. like this `if( lat && lng){ location([lat,lng])}`? Let me know if it fixes this issue.

Comment: the app rendered but then the map didn't

Comment: Initially, the data isn't loaded or retrieved from the  API, so when you create a location object it throws the error because lat and  LNG have not been yet passed. The map does display because the location object isn't created when there is no data. You will have to create another state to check when data  is loaded and  manipulate it accordingly